# CSS property "accent-color" not working on Safari

Tags: css, safari

I would like to change the color of a checkbox input. This is the code:

```
<input type='checkbox' class="checkbox" />

.checkbox {
    accent-color: #b10458;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
}
```

I have the expected result on Chrome and Firefox, but it's not working on Safari. How can I fix this?

Comment: accent-color isn't supported on Safari prior to v15.4 according to caniuse (i.e. it'll be OK on some devices now but obviously not all).